# How to get value of an object key from a Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

If I add these value on a Map:

```
var m = new Map();
m.set(1, "black");
m.set(2, "red");
m.set("colors", 2);
m.set({x:1}, 3);

m.forEach(function (item, key, mapObj) {
    document.write(item.toString() + "<br />");
});

document.write("<br />");
document.write(m.get(2));
document.write("<br />");
document.write(m.get({x:1}));
```

This prints:

```
black
red
2
3

red
undefined
```

Why I get `undefined` in the last line? And is there a way to retrieve the value of a object key stored in a Map?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need a reference to the object:

```
var m = new Map();
var o = {x:1};

m.set(o, 3);
m.get(o); //3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the object reference for getting the object. Any new literal is a new object, and is different.

```js
var obj = { x: 1 },
    m = new Map();

m.set(1, "black");
m.set(2, "red");
m.set("colors", 2);
m.set(obj, 3);

m.forEach(function (item, key, mapObj) {
    console.log(item.toString());
});

console.log(m.get(2));
console.log(m.get(obj));
console.log([...m]);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer-- almost identical to what I was about to paste in :)

Comment: But what if I have to retrieve this key afterwards in another context? I have always to store the reference to the original key objects somewhere?

Comment: @Simoyw, yes, otherwise you lost the reference. you could map the key/value pairs into an array to get the object back.

Answer (score 0):

you have undefined simply because

```
document.write(m.get({x:1}));
```

the object you are fetching at this line is not the same as the one here

```
m.set({x:1}, 3);
```

try this:

```
var m = new Map();
var obj = {x:1};
m.set(1, "black");
m.set(2, "red");
m.set("colors", 2);
m.set(obj, 3);

m.forEach(function (item, key, mapObj) {
    document.write(item.toString() + "<br />");
});

document.write("<br />");
document.write(m.get(2));
document.write("<br />");
document.write(m.get(obj));
```